# Segue issue with SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm trying to segue from side menu page of `SWRevealViewController` and transfer data to another view controller. It is crashing and I'm getting this issue ` -[UINavigationController setStr1:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x7f8c92224c80 '

while I'm using `Reveal View Controller Push Controller` method to push to the other view controller.

On the other hand in other view controllers I'm using `SHOW` instead of `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController` and it is working fine not crashing. I'm using storyboard.

Please where would be my issue?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TESTTEST"]) {

        ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.str1 = @"data pass";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is probably because you are setting `str1` property of a `ViewController`, instead you should use a `CustomViewController *destViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the segue destination view controller is a navigation controller (which consequently doesn't respond to the setStr1 selector).  So it looks like your `ViewController` is embedded in a navigation controller in the storyboard.  If so, change your code as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TESTTEST"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        ViewController *destViewController = navigationController.topViewController;
        destViewController.str1 = @"data pass";
    }
}
```